# Grep for string containing several metacharacters and extract 3 lines after match

Tags: linux, grep

I'd like to grep for `1:N:0:CGATGT` within a file and extract the line containing `1:N:0:CGATGT` and 3 additional lines after (4 lines total for each match). I've tired to grep numerous ways, all yielding unsuccessful:

```
[ssabri@login2 data]$ history | tail -n 8
 1028  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -A4 "1[[:]][[N]][[:]]0[[:]]CGATGT" | wc -l
 1029  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -A4 "1[[:]][[N]][[:]]0[[:]]CGATGT$" | wc -l
 1030  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -A4 "1[[:]][[N]][[:]][[0]][[:]]CGATGT$" | wc -l
 1031  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -A4 -w "1[[:]][[N]][[:]][[0]][[:]]CGATGT$" | wc -l
 1032  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | egrep -A4 -w "1[[:]][[N]][[:]][[0]][[:]]CGATGT$" | wc -l
 1033  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -x -A4 -w "1:N:0:CGATGT" | wc -l
 1034  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -E -A4 -w "1:N:0:CGATGT" | wc -l
 1035  zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | grep -A4 -w "1\:N\:0\:CGATGT$" | wc -l
```

EDIT: The input files looks something like this:

```
[ssabri@login2 data]$ zcat A1_S1_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz | head -n 12
@J00153:28:H7LNWBBXX:8:1101:28625:1191 1:N:0:CGAGGT
ACNTGCTCCATCCATAGCACCTAGAACAGAGCCTGGNACAGAANAAGNGC
+
A-#<-<<FJJAJFFFF-FJJJJJAJFJJJFF-A-FA#JJJJFJ#JJA#FJ
@J00153:28:H7LNWBBXX:8:1101:29457:1191 1:N:0:CGATGT
GTNGTGGTAGATCTGGACGCGGCTGAAGGCCTGGGGNCCCGTGNCAGN
+
-<#<FJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJ#JJJJJJ#JJJ#
@J00153:28:H7LNWBBXX:8:1101:31000:1191 1:N:0:CCATGT
TCNAATTATCACCATTACAGGAGGGTCAGTAGAACANGCGTTCTGGTNGG
+
<A#<AFFJJJFJJJFJJJJJJFFFJ7A<<JJFJJJJ#JJJAFJJJJF#-A
```

Comment: I suppose you to use ack instead the grep.

Comment: Any insight on the command?

Comment: See here : http://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: There are no regexp metacharacters in `1:N:0:CGATGT`, just use it as-is.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -A3 "1:N:0:CGATGT" file
@J00153:28:H7LNWBBXX:8:1101:29457:1191 1:N:0:CGATGT
GTNGTGGTAGATCTGGACGCGGCTGAAGGCCTGGGGNCCCGTGNCAGN
+
-<#<FJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJ#JJJJJJ#JJJ#
```

sometimes simpler thinking is better, here you don't need any regex extensions since you're string matching without any special regex chars that will need escaping.  A(fter) context match should be 3 since you want 3 trailing lines (total will be 4 with matching line).

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what you did and how it works.

Comment: It also does not seem to work for this example. There are 23319335 instances of `1:N:0:CGATGT` in the file. This I know and I am able to grep these lines correctly. The issues seems to be if I take 3 lines after the match, plus the match I seem to be gathering 94139079 lines, not 93277340. When I send these lines to a file I see that the grep also gathered strings such as `1:N:0:CGATGA`!

Comment: if there are overlaps or two matches on the same line they will affect number of lines. `1:N:0:CGATGA` shouldn't match since the last `T` is missing. If so, your `grep` is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for a grep solution. However this is not the only option in text processing. If you use `awk` then this might be a solution:

```
awk ' BEGIN {line=4;} \
    /1:N:0:CGATGT/ {line=0; print $0; next;} \
    { if (line<3) { print $0; line = line+1; } } ' your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem you seem to be having with using grep and pulling out a fixed 4 lines, try this:

```
$ awk 'NF>1{f=0} $NF=="1:N:0:CGATGT"{f=1} f' file
@J00153:28:H7LNWBBXX:8:1101:29457:1191 1:N:0:CGATGT
GTNGTGGTAGATCTGGACGCGGCTGAAGGCCTGGGGNCCCGTGNCAGN
+
-<#<FJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFJJJJJJJJ#JJJJJJ#JJJ#
```

Rather than printing a fixed number of lines after a match, it will print from the first line where the last field is your target string to just before the next line that COULD contain your target string.

To identify any blocks that have some number other than 4 lines including the target, use this:

```
$ awk 'f && NF>1{ if (f!=5) print NR, f-1 | "cat>&2"; f=0} $NF=="1:N:0:CGATGT"{f=1} f{print; ++f}' file
```

It will output to stderr the input file line number and the count of the number of lines in the unexpected block.